# How to parametrize a hostname in Jenkins Publish over SSH?

Tags: jenkins

I'm going to have a new hostname each time, but all of them will belong to the same security group, so I can use the same .pem
. I would like to set the hostname as a build parameter and have something like this:
[Publish over SSH configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2m4L.png)
.        For now I'm getting the error: *"ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [Redis Performance Testing]. Message [java.net.UnknownHostException: **$EC2_INSTANCE**]]]"*

Is there any idea how I can achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: You cannot add environment variable in global configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing, but I haven't managed to use build parameters using the Publish Over SSH plugin. (Have you found an answer to this?)

However, the SSH plugin is able to do that.

So, if you just need to execute shell commands remotely, you can:

- Install the SSH plugin
- Define a SSH Site (On Global Configuration, SSH remote hosts) using ${EC2_INSTANCE} as the Hostname
- On the job, define the build parameter "EC2_INSTANCE" with the hostname.
- Use the build step "Execute shell script on remote host using ssh", selecting the SSH Site previously defined.

I'm still searching about how to also send files, like the Publish over SSH plugin does.